# ulong not declared in the scope in Android

Tags: android, c++

I am trying to compile the following code with cross compiler for the Android API version 14:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf ("Size of ulong %d ", sizeof(ulong));
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
test1.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test1.cpp:6: error: 'ulong' was not declared in this scope
```

How can I resolve this issue ? I'm new to the Android environment. :)

Comment: I'm equally surprised that you can use `printf`. It is not declared in `<iostream>` either.

Answer (score 0):

`ulong` is not typedefed in `iostream`. Use `unsigned long` instead. Or typedef it yourself like

```
typedef unsigned long ulong
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i could able to compile in ubuntu linux ?

Comment: @Whoami Surprising. I tried in my Dev-C++ which internally uses mingw and got the same error as yours. I think there are some specific changes in your Ubuntu set up. Grep for `ulong` in `/usr/include`

Comment: You may forgot a `;` symbol :p
`typedef unsigned long ulong;`